# Multiply parameter and textBox value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an input text box that is in a form, and I'm trying to retrieve the value and multiply it to the parameter.

It doesn't run and I'm not sure if there's a syntax error or if my retrieval of textbox value is incorrect.

```
 <script>    
 function product(parameter1) { 
     a=parseInt(document.myForm.myTextBox.value);
     return parameter1*a; 
 };
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name='myForm'>
Insert your number: <input id='myTextBox' value=''><br>
</form>

<input type='button' value='CLICK HERE' onclick='product()'>
```

Comment: But where do you want to return the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You miss an argument in the onclick trigger, it should be `="product(10)"`, where 10 is your paremeter1 argument.
2. I believe you would have to have a name on the input tag to access it the way you do, so an easier and probably faster way to access your input would be `document.getElementById('myTextBox')`
3. It is better to execute your `product()` function on form submit, rather than on button click event, since some users might want to just hit enter in the text field instead of the button, but then you would have to move it within the form boundaries and make it be `type="submit"`

**MODIFIED CODE:**

**js:**

```
<script>    
 function product(parameter1) { 
     a = parseInt(document.getElementById('myTextBox').value, 10);
     var result = parameter1*a;
     // alert(result);
     return result; 
 };
 </script>
```

**html:**

```
<form name='myForm' onsubmit="product(10); return false;">
Insert your number: <input id='myTextBox' value=''><br>
<input type='submit' value='CLICK HERE'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were calling method without argument. If you only want to retrieve value,  below is the code.  I dont know how ur going to use it

Insert your number:

```
<input type='button' value='CLICK HERE' onclick='product()'>


<script> 
function product()
{
parameter1=10;
 a=parseInt(document.myForm.myTextBox.value); 
 return parameter1*a; 
 }
 </script>
```